# Why does my VideoWriter return a video with black all around it?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm trying to use `VideoWriter` to export a video being recorded. Although it works, the video is in the top left corner and surrounded by blackness. I have no idea why this would happening. The video itself is being saved and I can see it but I don't know why there is so much empty space. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import picamera
import numpy as np
import cv2
import traceback
from pylepton import Lepton

def main(flip_v = False, alpha = 128, device = "/dev/spidev0.0"):
  # Create an array representing a 1280x720 image of
  # a cross through the center of the display. The shape of
  # the array must be of the form (height, width, color)
  a = np.zeros((240, 320, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
  lepton_buf = np.zeros((60, 80, 1), dtype=np.uint16)

  with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    #camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    #camera.framerate = 24
    #camera.vflip = flip_v
    #camera.start_preview()
    #camera.fullscreen = True
    # Add the overlay directly into layer 3 with transparency;
    # we can omit the size parameter of add_overlay as the
    # size is the same as the camera's resolution
    o = camera.add_overlay(np.getbuffer(a), size=(320,240), layer=3, alpha=int(alpha), crop=(0,0,80,60), vflip=flip_v)
    #Creating the VideoWriter object
    filename = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d  %H.%M.%S", time.localtime()) + ".avi"
    fourcc =  cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('I','4','2','0')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, 8.0, (60, 80))

    k = 0

    try:
      time.sleep(0.2) # give the overlay buffers a chance to initialize
      with Lepton(device) as l:
        last_nr = 0
        while True:
          _,nr = l.capture(lepton_buf)
          #resize the frame before writing it to a file
          resized_frame = cv2.resize(a, (60, 80))

          out.write(np.uint8(rezised_frame))

          if nr == last_nr:
            # no need to redo this frame
            continue
          last_nr = nr
          cv2.normalize(lepton_buf, lepton_buf, 0, 65535, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
          np.right_shift(lepton_buf, 8, lepton_buf)
          a[:lepton_buf.shape[0], :lepton_buf.shape[1], :] = lepton_buf
          o.update(np.getbuffer(a))

          # Once the program has run 2000 time break the loop
          k += 1

          if k == 2000:
                 out.release()
                 break

    except Exception:
      traceback.print_exc()
    finally:
      camera.remove_overlay(o)
```

Comment: It seems like the code is written to do what you describe a problem (crop 320x240 in 80x60). Unless I didn't understand. From what I can read, the camera runs at 320x240, the overlay shows the cropped top-left 80x60 box, and the written frame is obtained from the overlay.

Comment: Sorry the overlay was supposed to be commented out. When the video shows up on my screen it appears normal but for some reason the exported video is weird. I've never programmed in python before so I'm a little confused why this is happening.

Comment: Look at `resized_frame` (used to write the image), it uses `cv2.resize` with `a`. What is `a` (unclear variable name) ? It seems to be the buffer in which the overlay is written to, and it is indeed cropped from 320x240 to 80x60, which would lead to the results you had. It's a bit unclear what your code attempts to do. I guess you interact with a FLIR camera and need to combine two streams of information, but this is not evident from reading the code. I wish I could help you more, but I'm a bit confused myself by the code, and don't know this domain particularly well.

Comment: You're right, the problem I am having now is that I can't save `lepton_buf` which is supposed to be the normal 80x60 image provided by the FLIR.

Comment: You could try to save `a` just after `a[:lepton_buf.shape[0], :lepton_buf.shape[1], :] = lepton_buf`, the same way as you do for it before it is updated by `lepton_buf`.

Comment: should cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, 8.0, (60, 80)) be cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, 8.0, (80, 60)) instead?